# Adding a multifield with analyzer in existing field in existing index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an existing index in elasticsearch (version : 5.1.1) which has some documents index in it. 
A mapping in the index (say hardware) has a a field as follows :

```
"biosSerialNumber" :{
     "type":"keyword"
}
```

I want to add a field to it with analyzer as follows : 
    "biosSerialNumber" :{
         "type":"keyword",
          "fields":{
              "suffix":{
                   "type":"text",
                   "analyzer":"abc_analyzer"
              }
           }
    }

"abc_analyzer" analyzer already exists in the index settings.
Is it allowed? I have tried doing this using PUT commands which I have used to add new fields in the index.
But it does not seem to work.

Getting this error :

> {
>       "error": {
>           "root_cause": [
>               {
>                   "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
>                   "reason": "Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [analyzer : suffix_match_analyzer]"
>               }
>           ],
>           "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
>           "reason": "Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [analyzer : suffix_match_analyzer]"
>       },
>       "status": 400 }

Comment: Btw, cause for the error mentioned above is that, I was trying to add an analyzer to a 'keyword' field, which is not allowed (for the obvious reason that keyword type is not analyzed)!. This was a sample try-out. But the first question still remains.

Comment: Can you show the PUT command you have sent?

Comment: yes, just posted in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the error was because  I was trying to add an analyzer to a 'keyword' field, which is not allowed (for the obvious reason that keyword type is not analyzed)!. This was a sample try-out.

Also, now after running a PUT request to :

```
<elshost>/<index-name>/_mapping/<doc-type>
```

with the request body :

```
{
    "properties":{
        "asset":{
            "properties" :{
            "biosSerialNumber":{
                "type":"keyword",
                "fields":{
                  "suffix":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "analyzer":"abc_analyzer"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

worked.

I understand, for this to take effect on the existing data in the field, documents need to be re-indexed.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You can simply call `POST <elshost>/<index-name>/_update_by_query` in order to make sure all documents pick up the new field. NO need tou reindex from an external data source.

Comment: ohhk, that's awesome and very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Val, I have asked a new question w.r.t _update_by_query. Can you check? link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510637/updated-by-query-for-re-indexing-elasticsearch-documents